# Select part of a git commit

Tags: git

Every time I want to rewrite a commit to keep only a part of the diff, I go through this (off the top of my head, something may be off):

```
git rebase -i COMMIT~1
```

then select `e` for amend.

```
git reset HEAD~1  
git add -p # select the part I want
git checkout HEAD -- :/ # discard changes not selected
git stash
git reset COMMIT
git checkout HEAD~1 -- :/
git commit -u --amend
git stash pop
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Obviously, this is a terrible workflow. The problem is that the reset allows me to select the changes I want, but by moving the HEAD back I stop being able to amend the relevant commit.

I tried to do a `git checkout HEAD~1 -- :/` once I'm on the commit I want to amend and select the reverse diff, but it just got confusing.

What's a better alternative?

Comment: `git reset --patch`, `git add --patch`, `git checkout --patch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be very concrete here (as in "I did *exactly* these commands and got *exactly* this output") because there are a lot of moving parts.  There are a bunch of separate things to keep track of.

In this answer, I'll go over all the various parts, relatively fast.  If you're sure you know all of this, skip straight to the last section!

#### Commits, `HEAD`, the index, and the work-tree

First, remember that Git is all about the commits.  The commits are safe: they are stored permanently and incorruptibly.<sup>1</sup>  So once you make a commit, you have at least 30 days or so to get it back even if you tell Git to throw it out, e.g., by using `git reset`.  This is *not* the case for other items: specifically, work in your work-tree is *not* kept safe by Git.  (Your OS may or may not make some guarantees, e.g., on a Mac you can set up Time Machine for this.)  Work you've stuffed into the *index* (aka staging-area, aka cache) is somewhere in between, but it's best to think of it as not-permanent as well.

Next, you should remember that there are, at all times, *three* active copies of every (tracked) file.<sup>2</sup>  Two of these are in special Git-only format.  The three are:

1. the version in the current commit, which you can view with `git show HEAD:README` for instance (if the file is named `README`);
2. the version in the index / staging-area, which you can view with `git show :0:README`;
3. and of course, the version in the work-tree, which is an ordinary file, not in a special Git-only format.

The ordinary file is readable and writable, and you can view and  change it in your editor.  The one in the index is sort-of read/write as well: you can view it with the above `git show` for instance, and you can *copy* the work-tree version *into* the index using `git add`.  If you do `git add README`, that's a simple, direct write: the work-tree version goes into the index.

The copy in the current (aka `HEAD`) commit is read-only.  You cannot change it at all.  You can only change which commit is the current commit (at which point the old commit *is still there*, and you can keep using it).

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, commits are *mostly* permanent—they'll go away if there is no *name* by which you can reach them.  They are incorruptible in that if something does happen, Git will know and won't let you get the commit back out at all ... is that an improvement?  Seriously, though, you can just get the commit from elsewhere, or retrieve all the uncorrupted files through other means.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, there are *up to* three copies of tracked files.  An *untracked* file is a file that is not in the index (whether or not it is in the current commit), but is in the work-tree.  If it's not in the index, that obviously knocks out one of the three copies.  We'll worry only about tracked files, here.

---

#### Commits form a directed graph

Because each commit records its parent (or for merge commits, two or more parents), we can draw a graph if we're given some starting commit(s).  We can find a starting commit by using the current branch name, whatever that is—`master` or `feature/tall`, for instance—to which the name `HEAD` is attached.  The branch name holds the raw hash ID of the *tip* commit of that branch.  The tip commit itself then holds the raw hash ID of its parent commit, so we say that the branch name points to the commit and the commit points to its parent, and of course the parent also points somewhere, giving:

```
... <-parent <-tip <--branch(HEAD)
```

If we replace the big ugly hash IDs with single uppercase letters or even just a round `o`, and—making use of the fact that commits are read-only and hence never change—don't bother drawing the commit arrows properly, knowing that they always go backwards—we can draw this out more simply as:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

We want to keep the arrow for the branch name, because these names *move* over time.

#### Making new commits with `git commit`

If you make a new commit in the usual way, by running `git commit`, Git:

- packages up everything in the index into a *tree* object (to be saved in a permanent commit);
- makes the new commit with its usual metadata (you as author and committer, your log message, etc., and the *current* commit as the new commit's *parent*)—this allows Git to compute the hash ID for the new commit;
- makes the *new* commit become your *current* commit (so that now your commit and your index match).

If we start with a tiny repository with just three commits, all on the only branch, `master`, we start with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

To add a new commit `D`, we make it point back to `C` and then change the name `master` so that it points to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The keys here are to remember that whatever is in your index will go into the next *new* commit you make.  It will have the *current* commit as its parent.  The name, in this case `master`, changes to remember the new commit, so the commit that `HEAD` identifies changes, to be the new commit with its new hash ID.  The old commit is still there, it's just not `HEAD` any more.

Now we can look at `git reset`, which is a surprisingly complicated command.  We'll look specifically at the form of `git reset` that's spelled `git reset HEAD~1`.

#### `git reset` moves your HEAD

The argument to `git reset` here is a commit hash, or something that specifies a commit hash.  The name `HEAD` means *the current commit:* specifically, *find the current branch name to which `HEAD` is attached, and then find the commit to which it points.*  The `~1` suffix means *go back one parent link.*  So if `HEAD` is attached to `master` and `master` points to commit `D`, go back one from `D` to `C`.

The command then changes the current branch—which we just decided was `master`—so that it points to that specific commit.  What happens to the commit itself?  We already said that earlier: *nothing* (yet).  It just loses its *name*:

```
        D   [no name - abandoned]
       /
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can now use the name `master` to find commit `C`, which finds `B`, which finds `A` (which is a *root* commit—meaning it has no parents—so that everything stops here).  We can't find `D` any more, so it's now unprotected, and will *eventually* be reclaimed; but it's safe for at least 30 days by default, during which we can still use it if we have some way to identify it, e.g., have written down the raw hash ID somewhere.

#### `git reset` *also* resets the index, by default

When we ran `git reset` above, it did not just move `master`.  It also reset the index.  That is, before `git reset HEAD~1`, the index matched commit `D`, because we made commit `D` *from* the index.  After `git reset HEAD~1`, the index now matches commit `C`.  That's because `git reset` re-set it!  Git copies the special-Git-only-formatted files from the new `HEAD` commit into the index (which, remember, holds files in their special Git-only format).

We can tell `git reset` *not* to re-set the index, using `--soft`.  If we do that, the index will continue to match commit `D` (which still exists, but we can't reach it from `C`—those lines connecting commits all go only one way, backwards).

#### `git reset` leaves the work-tree unchanged, by default

There were three copies of each file, and `git reset` has by default changed two of them.  The third copy is in the work-tree: `git reset` leaves this third copy alone, by default.

We can tell `git reset` to re-set the work-tree too, using `--hard`.  If we do that, Git will modify the work-tree while it modifies the index.  When it copies special-Git-only-formatted files into the index to make them match commit `C`, it extracts those files into the work-tree too.

#### Summary: `git reset` is complicated; it does up to three things

Running this kind of `git reset` (there are more kinds!—but we'll ignore them for now) does up to three things, stopping after one, two, or all three:

1. First, it moves the current branch.  If told `--soft`, it stops now.
2. Then, it resets the index.  If told `--mixed`, or not told anything, it stops with this.
3. Third, if told `--hard`, it resets (the tracked files in) the work-tree *while* resetting the index in step 2.

For our purposes here, we'll mostly want method 1, `--soft`: leave the index and work-tree alone; or method 2, `--mixed` / the default: leave the work-tree alone.

#### About `git add -p` and `git reset -p`

We noted above that running `git add` on a file simply copies the work-tree version into the index.  That's quite straightforward, but what if you don't want that?  You could, of course, copy the file in the work-tree, then edit it into the shape you want to add, and add that:

```
$ cp README README.save
$ vim README
$ git add README
```

after which you can put the saved version back, since the index now has the one you want to commit:

```
$ mv README.save README
$ git commit
```

But there is a short-cut.  You can use `git add -p` to *patch* the index version.

What `git add -p` does, behind the scenes, is to diff the index version and the work-tree version.  Then, for each "diff hunk", Git shows you the hunk and asks if you want to apply it.  If so, Git extracts the index version into a temporary file, applies the patch, and copies the temporary file (rather than the work-tree version) back into the index.  This has the effect of patching, rather than copying-wholesale, the index version.  As you apply individual patches, you move the index version closer and closer to the work-tree version.  ([If you're Zeno of Elea, you never quite get there.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise))

You can do the same with `git reset -p`, which does the same kind of diff, but this time compares the index version with the `HEAD` version.  As you apply changes, you move the index version closer and closer to the `HEAD` version.

#### Cherry-picking a commit

There's a paradox of sorts in Git: a commit *is*, in a very real sense, a saved snapshot—it's the saved index contents, as we've been noting all along here.  But when you `git show` a commit, you see it as a *patch*.

The way this works is simple: since each commit records its parent, which is also a snapshot, Git can simply diff the parent against the child.  Whatever has *changed* between the two snapshots, that's the patch.

What `git cherry-pick` does, in effect, is to turn existing commits into patches, then apply the patch to your current `HEAD` commit to make a new commit.<sup>3</sup>  This has the effect of *copying* the picked commit, but not just taking its snapshot: Git takes the *change* and applies the *change* to a new base.

---

<sup>3</sup>Git actually uses the full power of its internal merge machinery to apply the changes, so it's more than just a simple patch, but that's the easy way to think about it.  For the curious, it's a three-way merge with the picked commit's parent used as if it were the merge base, the picked commit as the `--theirs` commit, and `HEAD` as the `--ours` commit.

---

#### Rebase = reset + repeated pick

Rebasing in Git, whether interactive or not, consists of starting with a `git reset --hard` and then doing a sequence of repeated cherry-pick operations.<sup>4</sup>  Git uses the "detached HEAD" mode trick, so that the branch name of the current (being-rebased) branch does not actually move until the rebase finishes, but in principle, rebase does this:

1. Enumerate all the commits to copy:

   ```
                D--E--F   <-- feature (HEAD)
               /
   ...--o--A--B--C   <-- mainline
   ```

   Here, we might choose to copy `D` through `F`.  (Note that Git cannot easily and sensibly cherry-pick a merge for rebasing, so rebase normally just tosses them out entirely.)
2. Reset (and detach) to the first commit to be copied-after, such as `C`.  This particular reset is a `git reset --hard`: it re-sets the work-tree too.
3. Cherry-pick each to-be-copied commit, one at a time.  If a merge conflict occurs during cherry-picking, stop and get help from the user.
4. At the end of this process, move the branch name to point to the final copied commit, re-attaching HEAD at this time.  The originals now have no proper name (but rebase leaves `ORIG_HEAD` pointing to them for your convenience):

   ```
                D--E--F   [ORIG_HEAD]
               /
   ...--o--A--B--C   <-- mainline
                  \
                   D'-E'-F'  <-- feature (HEAD)
   ```

   where the `'` marks denote that these are copies.

An interactive rebase simply adds an editor session before starting the copies in step 2.  Each `pick` command tells Git to do an actual cherry-pick, using the commit hash ID.  If you change `pick` to `edit`, Git stops after the cherry-pick, even if there were no merge issues.  If you change the `pick` to `reword`, Git runs the cherry-pick with `--edit` to let you alter the commit message.  There are a few more special cases (squash and fixup), which I won't go into here; and you can re-arrange the *order* of each cherry-pick by rearranging the `pick` commands.  But fundamentally, each commit-copy is a cherry-pick.

---

<sup>4</sup>Some rebase commands literally run `git cherry-pick` and some don't.  For most commits this doesn't really make any difference.  It only has a different outcome when `git apply -3` can mis-apply without falling back on three-way merge.  Constructing an example of this is nontrivial.

---

#### Using `git commit --amend`

We described the normal commit process above:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

You make some changes, copy them into the index with `git add`, and run `git commit`, and Git creates new commit `D` with `C` as its parent and makes `master` point to `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can, however, tell `git commit` to use, not `C`, but `C`'s *parents*, using `git commit --amend`.  This packages up the index just as before, but then makes new commit `D` that points back to commit `B`:

```
     C   [abandoned]
    /
A--B--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Since Git *finds* commits by starting from the one that the current branch points-to, if we look at the set of commits now, we'll see `D`, then `B`, then `A`.  It's *as if* we somehow changed commit `C` into commit `D`—but we didn't.

Note that this uses the index and work-tree in the same way as always, so we can combine this with interactive rebase.

#### Using interactive rebase to build a new history

Suppose we start out with this chain of commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and we did something wrong in commit `G`, or want to split it, or otherwise do something-or-other.  We can find the ID of commit `F`, or something that identifies commit `F`, and run `git rebase -i` with that.

The thing that identifies `F` the most easily is to use `HEAD~3`, because the `~3` suffix counts back three: `I` (0), `H` (1), `G` (2), `F` (3).  So we run:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

and get three `pick` commands, that will copy `G`, then `H`, then `I` after `F` to give us:

```
       F--G--H   [abandoned]
      /
...--E--F'-G'-H'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

We change at least the first `pick` to `edit`, so that Git does the cherry-pick and then stops, leaving us with this intermediate version of the graph:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E--F'  <-- HEAD
```

(his is that special "detached HEAD" mode).  The index and work-tree currently match commit `F'`.

We did something wrong—maybe just *too much* and we want to split it—in `F'`, so now we can use `git reset -p` to interactively *undo* things in the index.  Or we can run `git reset --mixed HEAD~1` to *discard* `F'` while keeping the work-tree changes, then run `git add -p`.  We must remember which one we did because one *discards* `F'` and the other keeps it.

Let's say we keep `F'` for a moment, using `git reset -p`.  We alter the index a bit.  We can then run `git commit --amend` to make a new commit, let's call it `F''`, that's like `F` and `F'` but uses whatever is in the index now.  Because we add `--amend` to `git commit`, we get `F''`s parent set to `E`, not to `F'`:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E--F''  <-- HEAD
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

Or, let's say we discard `F'`, using `git reset --mixed`:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E   <-- HEAD
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

Now we need to `git add -p` to accumulate work-tree changes into the index.  When we're done, we run `git commit` (without `--amend`) and make our new commit `F''`:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E--F''  <-- HEAD
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

In either case, we are now ready to run `git add` again, to take *more* changes from the work-tree.  Let's commit that too, and call this commit `I` since the tick marks are getting silly:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E--F''-I  <-- HEAD
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

Now we can run `git rebase --continue` to have Git cherry-pick `G` to `G'` and `H` to `H'`:

```
       F--G--H   <-- branch
      /
...--E--F''-I-G'-H'  <-- HEAD
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

and once all the commits are in, Git will move and re-attach the branch name and we have:

```
       F--G--H   [ORIG_HEAD]
      /
...--E--F''-I-G'-H'  <-- branch (HEAD)
      \
       F'  [abandoned]
```

which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 4):

If you do a soft reset to the previous commit than you can rework your last commit without going through an interactive rebase:

```
git reset head~1 --soft
```

This will also make it easy to turn a single commit into multiple smaller commits.

However, this will likely only work well to rework the *last* commit.  If you do it for multiple commits, ie `head~2`, you'll collect all the changes of the past two commits in your staging area.  This is still useful, but is a different scenario then what you're describing as your desired workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the short and helpful answer ;-)